# WordPress shortcode with quotation marks

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I need to have quotation marks in my shortcode parameter like this:

```
[shortcode filter="taxonomies.pa_color:"red" AND visible:true AND stock>0"]
```

As you can imagine, the shortcode doesn't work like this.
Unfortunately I can't change or remove the quotation marks.
Is there any way to enter the value with `"`?

I tried to use `&quot;` instead of `"` like this:

```
[shortcode filter="taxonomies.pa_color:&quot;red&quot; AND visible:true AND stock>0"]
```

But it doesn't work either.

Escaping the `"` with `\"` also has no positive effect.

Is there any other way to do it?

I can't make extra parameters for the values because it's never clear which and how many attributes will be used in the shortcode.

Answer (score 2):

Tried with?

```
[shortcode filter='taxonomies.pa_color:"red" AND visible:true AND stock>0']
```

Comment: yes, that was my first try. Doesn't work :-(

Comment: what do you see on frontend? it breaks?

Comment: I see the shortcode in plain text

Comment: I looks like the `AND` gets filtered out!?